# Monitor showing the same desktop twice

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xrandr

I bought a new 43" 4k monitor. Due the limitation of graphic card I had to manually add th resolution which I wanted. I am trying to sqeeue as many pixels as I can get for a decent refresh rate.

When I use the below values my computer works fine and the display is decent enough. However the desktop seems to get get duplicated on the monitor. I have attached the image to explain not sure why there is an overlap.[image]

- cvt 2880 1575 35
- sudo xrandr --newmode "2880x1575_35.00"  214.25  2880 3048 3344 3808  1575 1578 1588 1609 -hsync +vsync
- sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2880x1575_35.00
  -xrandr --verbose --output HDMI-1 --mode 2880x1575_35.00

Thank you,v

---

update Aug/13/2017

The below config works fine. If I increase the width pixel then it starts to duplicate. The more pixel I add the more the duplicate workspace show up.

- cvt 2048 1152 60 // The refresh rate does not affect the issue.
- sudo xrandr --newmode "2048x1152_60.00"  197.00  2048 2184 2400 2752  1152 1155 1160 1195 -hsync +vsync
- sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2048x1152_60.00
- xrandr --verbose --output HDMI-1 --mode 2048x1152_60.00

Answer (score 1):

after adding mode you should run xrandr with both displays as parameters.

So after this `xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2880x1575_35.00` you should run `xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI-1 --mode 2880x1575_35.00 --right-of eDP1`

in this command I assume that your primary laptop display is eDP1 you can get them by running `xrandr` without parameters and that 1920x1080 is resolutio you want on laptop on other side for a 43" display you use new mode don't forget the last part of that --right-of eDP1 which instructs to place a display right of the `eDP1`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. The laptop display is workign fine the new 43" 4k still shows the desktop twice.

Comment: It might be that you are using incorrect size of the mode.
If you want 16x9 resolution then you need 1920/1080.0 * 1575 which equals 2800 not 2880. Also why so low refresh rate?

Comment: sorry 2800 did not work. I am using a low refresh rate as my card can't take the load. It can only handle 200 pixel clocks. You can read more about it here https://medium.com/@ValdikSS/how-to-use-high-resolutions-with-older-hardware-58577d91b1f8